# Power Apps combo box not searching unique list of job titles

Tags: powerapps

I have a combo box that is pulling unique job titles from O365, but it's not searching the list of job titles. It does pull a list and you can select one just the search isn't working.

In the Items field of the combo box, I have the following:

```
Sort(
  Distinct(
    Filter(
      Office365Users.SearchUser({searchTerm:ComboBox2.SearchText,top:999}),
      !IsBlank(JobTitle)),
    JobTitle),
  Value,
  SortOrder.Ascending)
```

The primary text and SearchField text of the Fields property both have Value selected. This is the only choice I have. I'm not able to select Job Title.

What do I need to do so that I can search the list of job titles?

Answer (score 0):

The [Distinct function](https://learn.microsoft.com/power-platform/power-fx/reference/function-distinct) will return a list of distinct values of the column you specified (in your example: 'JobTitle'), but the schema of the returned table will always have a single column called 'Value'. But the records from that table will contain the values from the JobTitle column returned by Office365Users.SearchUser.

If you want to reference that column using the name 'JobTitle', you can use the RenameColumns function to do so:

```
Sort(
  RenameColumns(
    Distinct(
      Filter(
        Office365Users.SearchUser({searchTerm:ComboBox2.SearchText,top:999}),
        !IsBlank(JobTitle)),
      JobTitle),
    "Value",
    "JobTitle"),
  Value,
  SortOrder.Ascending)
```

Comment: That's good to know that I can do that. That still leaves me with the issue of not being able to search the lists of job titles from the combo box.

Answer (score 0):

```
Filter(
  Office365Users.SearchUser({top:999}),
  !IsBlank(JobTitle) || StartsWith(JobTitle, ComboBox2.SearchText)
)
```

Please note that this will only filter after the first 999 results are returned. The searchTerm only works on display name, given name, surname, mail, mail nickname and user principal name.

Consider using `SearchUserV2` as `SearchUser` is deprecated. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/connectors/office365users/#search-for-users-(v2)

```
Filter(
  Office365Users.SearchUserV2({top:1000}).value,
  !IsBlank(JobTitle) || StartsWith(JobTitle, ComboBox2.SearchText)
)
```

Comment: Did this answer your question?